# .env file not working even though i required it

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, sendgrid

I required .env in the first line of my server.js file and as well in the file that I'm using process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY.

It seems that the variable in the .env file is not recognized, the text is not colored.

when I run the program I get "API key does not start with "SG."", but it does.

controller.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
```

server.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
...
```

.env file

```
SENDGRID_API_KEY = 'SG.theRestOfTheAPIKey'
```

Comment: What happens if you console log the api key out? - usually .env files have no spaces and no quotes. Try SENDGRID_API_KEY=SG.theRestOfTheAPIKey

Comment: @Bergur I get undefined

Answer (score 1):

Try removing double quotes and the spaces between the variable definition in the `.env` file. It might be the issue:

```
SENDGRID_API_KEY=SG.theRestOfTheAPIKey
```

Comment: didn't work for me, I just put the API key in sgMail.setApiKey and it worked, but the problem I have now is that I get 403 forbidden error from sendgrid